# googlesheets4 - specify col_types using vector

Tags: r, google-sheets, googlesheets4

I am trying to read a google sheet with many columns (`gs1`) into R. I also have a separate data frame in R (`df_col`) that has a list of the columns in `gs1` along with their formats. Is there a way to read `gs1` into R using the columns formats specified in `df_col`?

For example:
`gs1`

```
col1  col2  col3  
a     1     01/01/22
b     2     01/02/22
c     3     01/03/22
```

`df_col`

```
col_name    col_type
col1        c
col2        i
col3        D
```

To read in `gs1`:

```
gs1_df <- read_sheet(ss = "gs1", sheet = "Sheet1", col_types = df_col$col_type)
```

Whenever I currently follow the logic in the example above, I get an error stating `Error in check_length_one():! col_types must have length 1, not length 3.`

I'm guessing this is because there is an issue with directly calling the column of `df_col` in the function but I'm not sure how to get around that. Does the column need to be converted to a string before using it in the function?

Comment: @akrun If I specify the column types manually in the read_sheet function I don't get the error. However, as there can be hundreds of columns so I was looking to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/range_read.html) sets out that `col_types` is expected to be a

> string of readr-style shortcodes, with one character or code per column

You have currently got the short codes correctly defined, but in a vector of length `nrow(df_col)`. You need to convert it to a string (or technically a character vector of length one).

```r
col_types  <- paste(df_col$col_type, collapse = "")
gs1_df <- read_sheet(ss = "gs1", sheet = "Sheet1", col_types = col_types)
```